# How do I programmatically move Spaces' focus to a particular Space a window I want to focus on lives on Mac OS X with Objective-C?

Tags: macos, cocoa, window, spaces, mission-control

In my OSX menubar application, the user can open a particular application `NSWindow` from a dropdown menu item. Being a menubar application, this is accessible from **any Desktop** (a Desktop as in a *Mission Control 'Space'*).

I've got a reference to the window programmatically.

Say the user has clicked the menu item while on **Desktop 1**, the currently active Desktop. Naturally, the `NSWindow` is created, opened, brought to front. It now lives on **Desktop 1**

The user browses to **Desktop 2**, so that it's now the active Desktop.

The user clicks on the menu item again.

Since the window is already open on **Desktop 1**, I'd like Spaces to automatically bring set the active Desktop to **Desktop 1** again, so that the user can see the window he/she wanted to see.

How do I programmatically achieve this with Objective-C Cocoa in OSX?

Comment: Does `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` not work for menu bar applications?

Comment: Did you figure this one out man? Im trying to do same, I have PID of window i want to focus and now need to ensure the desktop is focused then the window is focused.

Comment: Sadly I no longer work on the project that prompted the question. I don't think I did find a solution.